How to pass client id and client secret from OAUTH 2.0 redirect to callback API
I was trying to set upDdropbox OAuth in my app, the following is the handler for grantapi, the grant api redirects the user to dropbox authentication page its address is localhost:8089/api/grant
func DropboxGrantCodeHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    queryParams := url.Values{}
    queryParams.Set("client_id", "myclientid")
    queryParams.Set("token_access_type", "offline")
    queryParams.Set("response_type", "code")
    queryParams.Set("redirect_uri", "http://localhost:8089/api/callback")

    url := &url.URL{
        Scheme:   "https",
        Host:     "www.dropbox.com",
        Path:     "/oauth2/authorize",
        RawQuery: queryParams.Encode(),
    }
    http.Redirect(w, r, url.String(), http.StatusSeeOther)
}

It redirects to dropbox oauthpage, I registered my callback API http://localhost:8089/api/callback as my redirect_uri in my dropbox app console.
Here in the code I hardcoded clientid, but I can modify my code and receive clientid  in the request. Consider the following scenario, following is the my callback API
func DropboxCallBackTokenHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println("entered to  call back api")
    code := r.URL.Query().Get("code")
    data := url.Values{}
    data.Set("code", code)
    data.Set("grant_type", "authorization_code")
    data.Set("redirect_uri", "http://localhost:8089/api/callback")
    data.Set("client_id", "myclientid")
    data.Set("client_secret", "myclientsecret")
    url := &url.URL{
        Scheme: "https",
        Host:   "api.dropboxapi.com",
        Path:   "/oauth2/token",
    }
    client := &http.Client{}
    tokenRequest, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodPost, url.String(), strings.NewReader(data.Encode())) // URL-encoded payload
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, "error during constructing  New Request,error is "+err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
    }
    //r.Header.Add("Authorization", "auth_token=\"XXXXXXX\"")
    tokenRequest.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    resp, err := client.Do(tokenRequest)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, "error during constructing  New Request,error is "+err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    body, err := io.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, "error during reading response,error is "+err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
    }
    if resp.StatusCode != http.StatusOK {
        http.Error(w, "error response,error is "+string(body), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
    var tokenResponse TokenResponse
    // Decode the response body into the response variable
    if err := json.Unmarshal(body, &tokenResponse); err != nil {
        // return response, fmt.Errorf("error decoding response: %v, body: %s", err, string(body))
        http.Error(w, "error in unmarshalling,error is "+err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
    }
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(tokenResponse)

}

Actually what my requirement is when Dropbox redirects to my callback handler , I also want to get my clientid and client secret, not as I hardcoded, because I have many Dropbox account and I want to get access token of the account which user request.

Either stick them into the session, before you send the user to the authorization URL, or stick the client ID into the state parameter. (But in that case, it should really only be the client ID, don't expose the client secret in URLs that might show up in a browser history. Use the client ID to go look up the matching client secret.)

You mentioned wanting to dynamically get the client ID/secret because you will have multiple Dropbox accounts connecting, but it's worth noting that you can (and usually should) use the same Dropbox API app client ID/secret for the multiple different Dropbox accounts connecting to your app.

The client ID and secret only identify the app itself, not the accounts, and can be used to connect the multiple different end-users of your app. The "authorization code", which is the code variable in this case, as well as the resulting access token/refresh token, are specific to the user account used to authorize the app.

If you do need to switch between different app registrations for whatever reason though (e.g., perhaps they have different access types), you can use the session or state strategies as CBroe mentioned, but as they said, keep the client secret a secret. You can find information on the state parameter in the /oauth2/authorize documentation here.

@Greg i didnt understand what you really meant. because i intended to allow users to create their own dropbox account for storing their private files. and after creating dropbox account , an app with client_id and client_secret can be created for their account from the dropbox app console. then how can this client_id and client_secret can be same for every dropbox acoount.

Each user can and should create their own Dropbox account to storing their own files, but they do not need to each register their own Dropbox app. You, as the developer of the app, only need to register the app once. Each end-user user would then authorize your one app to connect to each of their Dropbox accounts.

@Greg i want to make a curl command for getting users  files temporary link, if i am creating a token based on my client_id  and my client_secret and curl the following
curl -X POST https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/get_temporary_link \     --header "Authorization: Bearer <get access token>" \     --header "Content-Type: application/json" \     --data "{\"path\":\"/video.mp4\"}" 
how iam going to get their file.

To make an API call like that, you would use an access token (in place of "" in this snippet). That access token would be specific to the user's account, and would enable access to the files in that user's account.

@Greg for getting users access token i want users accounts client secret and client id. for that each users dropbox account want to have their own app.

Each user does not need their own app registration. Your app can use your one client ID and secret pair to send each user through the app authorization flow, which would result in an access token/refresh token specific to their account. You can have multiple end-users connect your one app like this.

by authorization do you means authoization of my app or authorizaton of the dropbox account.

I'm referring to when a user authorizes the app (in this case, your app) to connect to their account.
